# Align logo, header and menu

Tags: html, css

How to align a logo, header text and menu all on one line, with the logo aligned left, followed by the header text and the menu right? Most answers I have seen are for two elements (e.g., logo and menu).

For example, in the example below, the image div and the text div should align left (they do) and the menu div should alight right (it doesn't). They all also should vertically align (the menu div doesn't). See also http://jsfiddle.net/ecodiv/0xk935n6/

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="text">Header text</div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">menu 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.header {
}
.header .image {
    background-color: red;
    width: 70px;
    height: 93px;
}
.header .text {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.header menu {
    float:right;
}
.menu ul {
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.menu li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 8px;
}
.image, .text, .menu {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: To allow for a more fluid design you may want to look into using display: table-cell instead of floats in the future :).

Comment: That looks like an interesting alternative. I'll have a look, also to see if it deals better with vertical alignment of logo, text and menu

Comment: @callum - table-cell options works nice with three tables, thanks again. One problem is that I can't right align the text in the most right table-cell  (http://jsfiddle.net/ecodiv/j2kqrcmc/)

Comment: The problem here is because you are floating the menu items - if you add "display: inline-block" to your menu class, this works as you want it to ^^.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a dot notation for class in your CSS.

Instead of

```
.header menu {
    float:right;
}
```

write

```
.header .menu {
    float:right;
}
```

Also, if you want your `.text` and `.image` to be in the same line as `.menu`, just add `float: left` to both of these...

Comment: Thanks, that was a sloppy error, and an easy solution :-).  However, now all area aligned to the top, vertical-align: bottom does not do anything. Any idea?

Comment: @Paulo vertical-align property does not work on ```display: block```

Answer (score 1):

you can change to use `position: absolute` on the `menu` div and then set `right: 0; bottom: 0;`, this will align the `menu` to extreme right and bottom.

```
.header {
    position: relative;
}

.header .menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border:2px solid green;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0xk935n6/3/)

Comment: @Paulo you selected the first answer, kosturko's answer, as best answer, I am having a question in my mind, how it has solved your problem? the menu is not even aligned right? am I right? I just asked this because I was keeping to think about this so I just asked from you.. don't mind it.

Comment: I accepted it because it solved the question as stated initially. I only realized / encountered the other issues after. But really, your and Kosturkos answers were both very helpful, for which my thanks. I am still considering Callum's suggestion also, which looks appealing, but I haven't had the time to properly try it out.